# Can't install Eclipse on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos-high-sierra

Trying to install Eclipse (latest version) onto MacOS High Sierra.  After extracting the file "eclipse-java-luna-R-macosx-cocoa.tar.gz", I copy the resulting Eclipse folder into my Applications folder.

I then attempt to run the Eclipse application and get an error saying:

```
Eclipse quit unexpectedly
```

I have tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Eclipse.  My Macbook Pro is a late 2015 15" edition.

Comment: Eclipse Luna is very old. Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) is the current Eclipse and runs fine on macOS.

Comment: I seem to have Google'd into an old version by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on MacBook Air.

I resolved it by downloading the **eclipse-installer** : http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/eclipse/oomph/epp/photon/R/eclipse-inst-mac64.tar.gz

After extracting the file a **.app** file is created. Click on that file(it will open a app).

The app is basically a Eclipse installer.

Choose the Eclipse IDE you want to install and follow the mentioned steps.